# Socket implementation with ObjectInputStream - can't read object

Tags: sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

For a Java class I am taking, I need to use sockets to pass data back and forth between client and server.  While I can get examples to work passing string data, I need to be able to pass custom class objects (i.e. a product) and lists of these objects back and forth.  I cannot get the server piece to successfully read the input.  I tried to create a simple example of my code to see if anyone can pinpoint the issue.  I do understand that I don't have the code complete, but I cannot even get the server to read the object the the class is writing to the stream (in this case, I am writing a string just in an attempt to get it to work, but need to read/write objects).  Here is my code.  I have spent hours and hours trying this and researching other people's questions and answere, but still can't get this to work.

Here the sample code:

simple server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class simpleServer {

    public static final int PORT_NO = 8888;
    static ObjectInputStream serverReader = null;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NO);
        System.out.println("... server is accepting request");
        Object myObject = null;
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("creating reader");
            ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            serverReader = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("created reader");
            try {
                System.out.println("try to read");
                myObject = serverReader.readObject();
                System.out.println("read it");
                System.out.println(myObject);
                if (myObject != null) objOut.writeUTF("Got something");
                else objOut.writeUTF("got nothing");
                if ("quit".equals(myObject.toString())) serverSocket.close(); 
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("cath for readobject");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("other error");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

simple client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket socket;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", ProductDBServer.PORT_NO);
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        ObjectInputStream  objIn  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 

        objOut.writeUTF("loadProductsFromDisk");
        objOut.flush();
        String myString = objIn.toString();
        //System.out.println(myString);
        if (!"quit".equals(objIn.toString().trim())) {
            //System.out.println("reading line 1");
            String line;
            try {
                line = (String)objIn.readObject();
                //System.out.println("line is " + line);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            objIn.close();
            //System.out.println("result: " + line);
        }

        System.out.println("closing socket");
        socket.close();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Unknownhostexception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("ioexception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}
```

The code appears to run to the point on the server side where it trys to read the object I sent, and then dies.  Can someone see what I am doing wrong?  This seems to be such a simple thing to do, and yet I can't seem to get it to work.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: first I wondered why do you ObjectStream for communication between server and the client when you just send String! second, when you send UTF, you need to read UTF, no Object, just change the "myObject = serverReader.readObject();" line in server with "myObject = serverReader.readUTF();"

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.  I was sending a string partly just for proof of concept, but also because I'm going to have to send both strings and objects.

Comment: So this is my first time posting a question.  I would like to show that you answered my question, but I can't find that option the way that StackOverflow help says that I should have.  It may be that you commented rather than answered - I am not sure, but I would like to show that you did answer my question.  Thank you!

Comment: no need buddy, I just happy I could help, doesn't matter comment, answer, smoke, . . ., thank you :D, have good app

Comment: btw, why don't you run a separated thread for each request come to the server, the current approach is in single-thread manner, if two client try to connect, the second one has to wait until the first one get finished

Comment: Because this is just for a class and it's only going to be called once for one test.  :)

Answer (score 0):

To write objects to an ObjectOutputStream you need to call writeObject().

Not writeUTF().

To read objects from an ObjectInputStream you need to call readObject().

Not toString().

Comment: Thank you.  User2511414 above let me know I needed to readUTF (rather than readObject) if I did the writeUTF.  I need to be able to write both strings and objects, so I started with the string and couldn't get that to work.  I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

See in your code:

```
// Simple Client 
objOut.writeUTF("loadProductsFromDisk");           // Line 8
```

You are sending the String `"loadProductsFromDisk"` in the UTF-8 format towards the server side.
So in order to receive it and read it over the server side, you will need something like this:

```
String clientReq = serverReader.readUTF();
```

Where, `serverReader` is your `ObjectInputStream` object.

Otherwise, if you wish to send and receive objects you must use the
`writeObject()` & `readObject()` methods respectively.